# is this use of dynamic a bad practice?

Tags: c#, linq, object, dynamic

I was wondering if this code is a bad practice.

```
..
var StoresInData = (from s in MainData
                    orderby s.LocationCode
                    select new
                      {
                          s.LocationCode,
                          s.LocationShortName,
                          s.LocationName
                      }).Distinct().ToList();
..
foreach (var store in StoresInData)
    {
       CreateReportForStore(store);
       ..
       ..
    }
```

and in the CreateReportForStore function:

```
private void CreateReportForStore(dynamic store)
        {
            var a = store.LocationCode;
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            ..
            ..
        }
```

Is the use of dynamic a bad practice to pass anonymous object in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Using dynamic to pass around anonymous objects is a bad code smell. If I were reviewing someone's code, I'd tell them to make a data class for it.

Comment: Also, note that `dynamic` still maintains accessibility modifiers. Since anonymous types are `internal` (non-contractual), passing them as `dynamic` in a different assembly will cause errors. Just make your own type, it's well worth the time. Especially if the C# compiler team decides to make them `private` in the future :P

Answer (score 3):

If you need to pass it around, it's a good idea to use typed classes. Makes the code more readable and maintainable. Also it makes it less error-prone.

Comment: Not to mention the performance overhead, since the type is resolved at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the only things that I use dynamics for is returning a subset of object properties from an API.  If its being passed around on the back end, then I would create an object for it.